# c# Using ArrayLists inside properties

Tags: c#, class, properties

I want to be able to have a class Named Musician, with a rule/Property called Hits( which is an Array-list, with two methods called ListHits() and AddHits(string)

ListHits returns a string containing all the hits separa
ted by a comma

AddHit – adds a hit to the Hits arrayList. Each hit is
a string between 1 and 50 characters long with no l
eading
or trailing white space.

I have no idea how to go about doing this im familiar with collections and adding values to Lists and i know how to set basic properties

-- i have tried for hours on end please HELP!

```
public class Musician : Celebrity
{

    private string _hits;

    public string Hits
    {
        get { return _hits; }
        set
        {

            if (value.Length < 1)
            {
                throw new Exception("need more then 2 characters");
            }
            if (value.Length > 50)
            {
                throw new Exception("needs to be less then 50 characters");
            }

            else
            {

                _hits = value.Trim();

            }

        }
    }

    public Musician()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

}
```

Comment: Show us what you have and we can help you build on it. As a side note, a `List<string>` is more appropriate than an `ArrayList`..

Comment: "i have tried for hours on end please HELP!"
If this is true please post some code and narrow your problem down to a single question or two.

Comment: Sorry, first time posting -- there you have it

Comment: That's a start.. So what specifically is the problem?

Comment: Okay so Hits is a property which contains an arrayList of hits for an 'artist'. Each
hit is a string between 1 and 50 characters long with no leading or trailing white space. Hits is an array list
which is private and can only be accessed by the methods listHits and addHit

im forced to use an arrayList

Comment: its part of extension optional activities my teacher has set its doing my head in :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you should try using a `List<string>` rather than an `ArrayList`. `ArrayList` was what you used before C# added [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in version 2.0. `List<T>` allows you to retain typing information about the items in the list, which enables you to more easily write correct code.

The code you posted didn't seem to really match the details you were asking for, but something like this should do what you specified:

```
public class Musician
{
    private List<string> _hits;

    public string ListHits()
    {
        return string.Join(", ", _hits);
    }

    public void AddHit(string hit)
    {
        /*
         *  validate the hit
         */
        _hits.Add(hit);
    }
}
```

The key is using `string.Join` to convert the `_hits` list into a comma-delimited string. From there, the rest is just basic C# concepts.

Comment: this was helpful but i need to use an arrayList

Comment: Okay so Hits is a property which contains an arrayList of hits for an 'artist'. Each hit is a string between 1 and 50 characters long with no leading or trailing white space. Hits is an array list which is private and can only be accessed by the methods listHits and addHit im forced to use an arrayList